# On/Off One Button Timer Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, onclick

I am working on a game project and I am trying to do a timer for a cannon charge. I am trying to use setInverval and clearInterval on the same onClick button to to control such timer.

Here is my code:

```
function playerOneCharge(){
    if(pOnePower==0){
    pOnePower = setInterval(function(){ myTimer()}, 100);
    }else{
        clearInterval(pOnePower);
    }
}

function myTimer(){
    ++pOnePower;
    console.log(pOnePower);
};
```

playerOneCharge is triggered when the button is pressed, pOnePower is set to 0.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: Ops, It doenst stop when I click the button again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't stop because you use same variable for counting and creating interval.

When interval is created unqiue id is assigned and clearInterval need that id to clear.

But you increased that id value by `++pOnePower` so when it comes to clearInterval  which he need interval id instead he get another which info doesn't exists in interval

Make separate two variable

Like this

```
var pOnePower=0;
var intVal=null;
function playerOneCharge(){
    console.log(pOnePower);
    if(!intVal){
    intVal = setInterval(function(){ myTimer()}, 100);
    }else{
        clearInterval(intVal);
        intVal=null;
    }
}

function myTimer(){
    ++pOnePower;
   console.log(pOnePower);
};
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/bgrbypq3/)**

Comment: check the red circle http://s9.postimg.org/ibtt3jeej/Capture.jpg?noCache=1447825332 @ReneRoger

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem here is you are using same variable pOnePower for incrementing variable and timer variable change the variable to something else like below as 'Test'

```
var Test;
    function playerOneCharge(){
        if(pOnePower==0){
        Test= setInterval(function(){ myTimer()}, 100);
        }else{
            clearInterval(Test);
        }
    }

    function myTimer(){
        ++pOnePower;
        console.log(pOnePower);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using a setInterval. The correct method is setTimeout and the corresponding clearTimeout.

```
var pOnePower;

function playerOneCharge(){
    if(pOnePower==0){
    pOnePower = setTimeout(function(){ myTimer()}, 100);
    }else{
        clearTimeout(pOnePower);
    }
}

function myTimer(){
    ++pOnePower;
    console.log(pOnePower);
};
    function myTimer(){
        ++pOnePower;
        console.log(pOnePower);
    };
```